# How to use existing On-Demand instance in spot fleet?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to reduce my expenses and want to start using AWS's spot pricing service. I'm completely new to it, but as I understand I can have instances running for certain amounts of time based on the price that will eventually stop running based on certain conditions. That's fine, I'm also aware you can have spot fleets, and in these fleets you can have an On-Demand instance for when the spot instance is interrupted.

I currently have a an On-Demand instance that hosts an ElasticBeanStalk application (it's an API), is there a way to use this instance inside the spot fleet so that when there's an available spot-instance it's servicing my EBS application then when the spot-instance is interrupted it just goes back to using my current On-Demand instance until another spot-instance is available?

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk supports spot instances, but I'm not aware of a way to make this part of Spot Fleet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, spot fleets don't work like this. If your spot instance gets terminated, **no on-demand replacement** is going to be created for you automatically. If it worked like this, everyone would be using spot instances in my view.

The on-demand portion of your spot fleet is separate from spot portion. This way your application will always run at **minimum capacity** (without spot). When spot is available, your spot instances will run along side your on-demand. This way you will have more computational power for cheap, which is very beneficial for any heavy processing application (e.g. batch image processing).

Details of how spot fleet and spot instances work are in  [How Spot Fleet works](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-fleet.html#on-demand-in-spot) and [How Spot Instances work](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/how-spot-instances-work.html) docs.

Nevertheless, if you would like to have such replacement provisioned you would have to develop a **custom solution** for that.

Comment: Oh I see, I was under the impression it could be used to replace a spot instance, if that were the case then yes you're right everyone would be doing that. I'm thinking then it would be better to use the reserved instances. Works out to be roughly the same. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Either that or change my application to use only spot-instances and start a new instance when the old one is interrupted? Not sure it's worth the trouble of setting up

Comment: @CharlesSmith No problem. And yes, reserved instances would be better if you know you need to run your instance for at least 1 year continuously.

Answer (score 0):

There's a third-party solution called Spot.io that not only replaces the spot instance for an on-demand instance in a scenario like the one you describe but it has an algorithm that anticipates the interruption event and stands up an On-demand instance and has it ready before the interruption occurs.